# Parse Cloud: Unable to return value of query of max value in a column

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform

I am new to the Parse cloud code, and would like to obtain the max value in a column of the Parse Database.

### Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("query_maximum", function(request, response) 
{
    var max =1;
    var DB = Parse.Object.extend("Recording_db");
    var query= new Parse.Query(DB);
    query.descending("Ref_int");
    query.first(
    {
        success: function(result)
        {  
                max = result;
                response.success("Max: " + max);                
        },
        error: function()
        {
                max =0;
                response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        },
    }); 
});
```

### Android:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("query_maximum", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() 
{
   public void done(String result, ParseException e) 
   {
       if (e == null)  
       {
           tv1.setText(""+result);
       }
   }
});
```

### Question:

The `tv1` returns a value of Max: [object Object] instead of the max value in that column.

Updates:
After adding `response.success("Max: " + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(result)));` in the success loop, the result in the device is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Then `max` is an object. Try writing it to the console to see if `result` contains a  property with the max value.

Comment: I have added  `console.log(result); ` in the success loop, just would like to ask where to see the console result? I cannot see in the `logcat`. Thx

Comment: Is this ran in a browser? If so look at the result in your dev tools (F12, open via keyboard.)

Comment: if it runs in android?

Comment: Then write it on page using `Object.keys(result);`

Comment: ADDITION: `JSON.stringify(Object.keys(result));`

Comment: the result is updated as in the question...not knowing what to do =(

Comment: The returned object is the first row of the sorted table.  To get an integer value from it, try result.getInt("Ref_int")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify my comment, the code retrieves a `Recording_db` object that is represented by the row with maximum `Ref_int`.  Treat this like a parse object in the cloud logging....

```
    success: function(result)
    {  
            max = result;
            response.success(max.get("Ref_int"));
            // use get here in javascript               
    },
```

and in the response...

```
public void done(Integer i, ParseException e)
{
    if (e == null)  
    {
        tv1.setText("" + result.getInt("Ref_int"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! It works! A bit further modification would be that in the response: `public void done(String result, ParseException e)`  to become `public void done(Integer i, ParseException e) `